# How do I find out which what fields are available?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm looking to access the values of the fields in `postSave()`.

```
public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {
  //what's in $webform_submission? can I use it to get field data that was saved/submitted?
}
```

How do I get which fields are available from `$webform_submission`? How do I access them?

I have a field whose machine name is *feedback_type. I need to access its properties from that function.

**UPDATE**

So essentially what I'm wondering is, is there a way to see the structure of the $webform_submission variable? so that I can retrieve the data that the user submitted? I'd prefer to be able to do a print of it whether that's to a file/log/etc. doesn't matter I'd just like to know the structure of the $message_submission and its fields.

Answer (score 0):

Might depend a little on what you're trying to do with those fields (get info/set info/adjust info), but here are a couple of things you could try:

**CustomHandler.php**

For submission data:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {

  // Get the submitted webform data.
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();

  // Get specific submission value.
  $myFieldValue = $data['field_name']
}
```

For webform field values (e.g. type = radios):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {

  // Get the webform fields (which will contain properties/attributes/values/etc.).
  $elements = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded();

  // Get field values.
  $fieldType = $elements['field_name']['#type'];
  $fieldTitle = $elements['field_name']['#title'];
  $fieldFirstOption = $elements['field_name']['#options'];['option_one'] // If you need the selected value that will be in ->getData(), or in ['#return_value'] key.

  // Get webform owner (not anonymous).
  $webformOwner = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getOwner();

  // Get owner values.
  $displayName = $webformOwner->getDisplayName();
  $userName = $webformOwner->getUsername();
  $userEmail = $webformOwner->getEmail();

  // And to set data values:
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();
  $data['myNewValue'] = $myNewValue;
  $webform_submission->setData($data);

  // If you need to find some other available methods, try:
  kint($webform_submission->getWebform());
}
```

Fields on the webform, e.g. `feedback_type`, `your_email`, `first_name` will be available inside the method `->getElementsDecoded()`.

Comment: To answer the first part, I need the fields because I'm passing those values to a separate API that we have. So I need to get the email address, name, feedback type (which is a hidden field). How would I view the available variables? I tried using kint() but nothing gets printed out most likely because it's reloading/navigating away. From the original form.

Comment: I've added a bit to the answer for getting owner info. Though if the email is a field on the webform, such as for anonymous users, it will just be a field you can access. Also, you can add an `exit;` after your `kint();` statement to stop other code from running, then just resubmit your form to see the kint readout.